# How to create a report, as a Word document, from data in a Sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint list that is used to record weekly activity, e.g. four columns for weeknumber, projectname, customername, comment

I'd like to be able to generate a report containing all the data for a particular week in the following format

- ProjectName 1

  - Customer 1

    - Comment 1
  - Customer 2

    - Comment 1
- ProjectName 2

  - Customer 3

    - Comment 1
  - Customer 4

    - Comment 1

I can do this by exporting the list to an Excel file and then writing some VBA to generate a Word Document, but I'm wondering if there is any way to cut out the Excel step.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Xml](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) ?

I found it quite a steep learning curve to get into, but very powerful. I'd suggest that this is a more elegant approach than vba (in that you are dealing with strongly-typed classes) but not necessarily quicker.

Answer (score 1):

So there's two parts to this

a) Getting the data from SharePoint.

b) Converting it into a Word document.

For a) You will probably end up running this remotly (i.e. not on the sharePoint server) as automating office apps on a server is not recommended - so you should look into the [SharePoint Web Services](http://geekswithblogs.net/mcassell/archive/2007/08/22/Accessing-Sharepoint-Data-through-Web-Services.aspx) to access your data.

For b) You can use
- Office Automation (via VBA or C#, VB.NET etc)
- Open XML as Pete suggests ([Example running in SharePoint](http://sharepointplace.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/programmatically-creating-word.html))
- A commercial component such as [Apose](http://www.aspose.com/) 
*The last two will allow you to run your code on the SharePoint server*

Answer (score 0):

There is nice example on [Github](https://github.com/ngs-doo/TemplaterExamples) (FoodOrder) on how to do it with Templater.

As author I highly recommend it ;)